# ArcGIS REST API - How to view the geoJSON results?

Tags: rest, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

How do you use the ArcGIS REST API to view the geoJSON results for fires? The URL is https://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/geomac_dyn/MapServer/3/ or https://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/geomac_dyn/MapServer/3?f=json but it isn't displaying the latest fire perimeter data just the metadata.

Comment: You have to make a query in order to see records. What are you trying to do with the data? Are you trying to add it to a web map?

Answer (score 0):

[ArcGIS REST URL](https://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/geomac_dyn/MapServer/3/query?where=objectid%3Dobjectid&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=5&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=geojson&__ncforminfo=UDqdkZGB6FGT0RX5WtBz-zjUkC9u0PWx6QuskhpMnQ3WurGb898tPFZk57Hkvlo0E1MpuAp1JAjoQsQ-FlH-J_EuURSoxjdfy7oUTSFU6Rf_fEeys9df2JiOCNSSpGqPbed6Ip4vjD1oqOP1l6039XXI944OKAsfczLv6cSmfJgm3MDSRXe8Laq1X-obIlzI3_woJgeyFa8D6PYW9zMdonf7ms_mdBrVF4h3JDpHn5wI6-hinYW-nWYjbDEmJS1rMaEL4Q8u4mFXPwtKhDrBY3avn4G1SdiEPPfeMcBbwxjXt4fvC2lsA_yQxX6wad_ilhF8QswlIOZ2hAqofik-PqPq66mvaD_dsRS2fE5cFLZY2Zlp3jCU-AMxlN8zXXfmVVP9aCa-KYPkfn3nzWkEzeiGrvdrdTMcvkIWees0jvFF0HpWOGLyxp2viCLMb_0GbXzOMvFtsd-dk5y5h1dD6FESJn6RXCtg59S2k7cyLugSq5SZSDj9TCX1uNpQv4ftzCqzh2ZSR2LpMj-BEir3sIeaN4CW8y7DiCAorwN5guPe9_VzHn1lxtL9ZQWTAuamfPa0b10ea6QPEChAbH53bwNOuqAug2_t5db2XJmX6YUgKhp26enAYmiVvQnbnX0w66lizgejGfNfe2txk-Tnz2yoUcE7Xojv75SvKSUYCizGNJTsnqjsyg%3D%3D)

I figured it out above with the help of the original commentator. [usgs.gov/arcgis](https://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/geomac_dyn/MapServer/3/query) has a query guide and you just need to know SQL Where commands.

i.e. query?where=active = 'Y'